# What should be our one exemplary question to be featured in the About page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, top-7

As of five minutes ago we have gained more control over our new and improved about page. Among other things we get to pick the exemplary question that is featured on that page.

See here for the list of eligible questions: http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/92078/possible-about-questions

I'm not too happy about the current choice. What says you?

Comment: In other news we can also edit the elevator pitch at the top and the two lists of questions we do and don't want. If you want to see them improved make a question about it.

Comment: The list of requirements is inferred by me and not necessarily accurate. We just have a few pages of eligible questions.

Comment: I like the current about page...

Comment: Do we want a question on a 'popular' game (e.g. D3), or something that fewer people will recognise?

Comment: @fredley I think that's less important as long as the question is relatively easily understood without much prior knowledge of the game.  As discussed briefly in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7692678#7692678), it should probably also be an in game problem or fact finding question rather than something like technical issues.

Answer (score 6):

My nomination.

[Do Blizzards from multiple Wizards stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/do-blizzards-from-multiple-wizards-stack)

Only 1.6k views, but well written question and answers, all upvoted.  No meta tags, which while not an explicit requirement, I think is a good idea.  Also nice and short without any major formatting (other than one link).

Comment: This is eligible

Comment: Okay, I've selected this as our current About question. See how it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and throw mine into the mix:

[Which walls are bombable?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45530/14775)

- 2700+ Views
- Two positive answers
- High...ish votes

Comment: This is eligible

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to nominate this question:

[How can I increase Skyrim's Volume?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35452/how-can-i-increase-skyrims-volume)

- 10k views
- 2 postive answers
- uses 2 tags